# Breeze js Basics for Non-EF

Tags: breeze

I am trying to piece together posts about config code for non-EF apps. It seems I need to:

```
      core.config.initializeAdapterInstances(
        new DataService({
            serviceName: serviceName,
            hasServerMetadata: false
        }));
```

So, although very silly, I cannot seem to find core.config.initializeAdapterInstances. How do I get this stuff to resolve??

thanks

M

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is that core is undefined, then try to add this line before your code

`var core = breeze.core;`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Actually, I believe that IS the answer to the question. The question I believe is "Where is 'core.config'?" to which the LONG answer is "The 'config' class has moved to 'breeze.config'; for backward compatibility it remains accessible from 'breeze.core.config'"